# symfony2 : Pass serivce to service (controller as service) through configuration

Tags: symfony, service, parameters

I am trying to pass my service, defined in other bundle to controller which is defined as a service but getting null in contractor.
I know we can do it by passing the service_container but need to know if I can pass only specific service to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If the name is unique, no problem here.

```
namespace Yourapp\OneBundle\Controller;

class OneController extends Controller
{
    public function oneAction()
    {
        $otherControllerManager = $this->get('youappOtherbundle.the_manager');
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Okay, it seemed to me that you could extend controller even it was a controller as service.
Why don't just "transmit" your required services as usual ?

In your services.yml

```
OneController.controller.service:
    class: Yourapp\OneBundle\Controller\OneController
    arguments: ["@templating", "@router"]
```

In your Controller:

```
public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating, UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
{
    $this->templating = $templating;
    $this->router = $router;
}
```

Comment: Ya, this can be done in controller, but I am not extending my Controller class to my controller as defining my controller as service.

Comment: I tried this way but I always get null in __construct arguments

Comment: Sorry, i cant help you more without your code :/
You should try better :P
link would help : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#alternatives-to-base-controller-methods